# Why does my PowerShell script not show colors when outputting the command. If I manually type the same command in PowerShell it appears

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have been pasting these same commands into PowerShell for months and thought it would be easier to just make a script that types the commands into PowerShell and runs them automatically without me having to Open PowerShell > Paste > Enter > Close Window.

**Manually Typed Commands**
P.S. (I press enter after each command line)

```
spicetify config current_theme Sleek
spicetify config color_scheme futura
spicetify apply
```

[Output Image 1^](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk59F.png)

**My PowerShell Script**

```
$myshell = New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell"
Write-Output "spicetify config current_theme Sleek"
$myshell.sendkeys("{ENTER}")
Write-Output "spicetify config color_scheme futura"
$myshell.sendkeys("{ENTER}")
Write-Output "spicetify apply"
$myshell.sendkeys("{ENTER}")
```

[Output Image 2^](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzLe3.png)

Comment: `Write-Output`, as the name implies, writes to the output stream. Whatever you write there is not also considered input -- that input happens to be echoed back to you on the console as you type it is another matter. If you want to encapsulate these commands, simply put them as-is in a script with the `.ps1` extension and execute them from there (`.\spicetify.ps1`). You can furthermore have this executed automatically when PowerShell opens by adding it to your [profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles).